# mysql how to edit an existing trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have installed mysql Query browser for `creating tables/ views/ procedures (In Ubuntu)`
But there is no option for creating triggers then where i should `create triggers or edit triggers`?

Which `browser` i should use to create triggers?

Comment: You can create and recreate triggers in mysql command line tool - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: thanks for ur answer. I think i have to do with command line.

Comment: ...also take a look at navicat and sqlyog GUI for linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access MySQL DB from the Windows OS, then try trigger editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition).

Also, have a look at this article - [dbForge Studio for MySql on Linux family operating systems](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dbforge/index.php/dbforge-studio-mysql-on-linux-operating-systems.html), it describes a way to run this tool under Linux.